# Control RTS line when communication via RS-485 serial

Tags: python, linux, pyserial, rs485

I'm trying to communicate over the serial interface RS-485 on a Linux machine with kernel 2.6.39. I'm using [this breakout board](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10124) together with the [pySerial](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/pyserial_api.html) module. When I write something via the interface often my data gets corrupted. On the product page of the breakout board someone mentioned:

> I’ve noticed from the beginning, that I need to have a delay of about 25 ms after I send serial data before I can bring the RTS line low otherwise the transmission gets corrupted or is not transmitted.

I discovered that the RTS line shortly gets high when I write bytes, but gets low immediately after writing. How do I keep that line high (for a bit longer)?

Comment: Usually the Linux serial port driver has to be configured into RS-485 mode using the **TIOCSRS485** ioctl. This ioctl takes a data structure that specifies how the RTS handshake signal is repurposed and should control the transmitter.  There's a parameter to specify the hold-up time that you're asing for.  Read http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/serial/serial-rs485.txt  You probably should do a get ioctl to read the structure, increase that hold-up time, and do a set ioctl.

Answer (score 0):

You can set RTS manually with:

```
setRTS(level=True)
```

and then clear it after a 25ms delay with:

```
setRTS(level=False)
```

Comment: No I tried it and it doesn't work. Read my answer for the reason.

Comment: You might have to disable flow control and do it manually with `setRTS`

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trial and error I think I found the problem. My presumption is that the RS-485 driver off the kernel is setting the RTS line to high for a short moment when I use serial.write(). serial.write() writes characters to /dev/ttyS1. From this moment the Linux driver for RS-485 controlls the serial bus in order to write the characters. During this operation it sets the RST line during the actual write moment for a short period to high.

I can't controll this write operation on a higher level, I think I've to hack into the driver or connect the RTS line to a different GPIO which I can control.